# How to accommodate concurrent authentication requests in LdapLoginModule

Tags: java, authentication, jaas

I use `com.sun.security.auth.module.LdapLoginModule` to authenticate users against Active Directory using JAAS. But i noticed when multiple users try to authenticate concurrently, it appears to be authenticating one after the other. But When i use `com.sun.jmx.remote.security.FileLoginModule` it works concurrently.

I would like to know is this a limitation in `LdapLoginModule` or is there a way to achieve 
this?